# SQL Query for Max Value of Grouping Till Date for All Dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some values which is  based on date for different groupings
For each grouping id, what is the max of value till a particular date.

Example

Date            Grouping Id  Value

2017-06-01  1                  100

2017-06-03  1                  101

2017-06-06  1                  103

2017-06-02  2                  200

2017-06-04  2                  210

2017-06-08  2                  220

2017-06-01  2                  1000

2017-06-05  2                  1020

2017-06-09  2                  1050

I need the output like below

Date             Grouping Id            Value

2017-06-01  1                  100

2017-06-02  1                  100

2017-06-03  1                  101

2017-06-04  1                  101

2017-06-05  1                  101

2017-06-06  1                  103

2017-06-07  1                  103

2017-06-08  1                  103

2017-06-09  1                  103

2017-06-10  1                  103

2017-06-01  2                  NULL

2017-06-02  2                  200

2017-06-03  2                  200

2017-06-04  2                  210

2017-06-05  2                  210

2017-06-06  2                  210

2017-06-07  2                  210

2017-06-08  2                  220

2017-06-09  2                  220

2017-06-10  2                  220

2017-06-01  3                  1000

2017-06-02  3                  1000

2017-06-03  3                  1000

2017-06-04  3                  1000

2017-06-05  3                  1020

2017-06-06  3                  1020

2017-06-07  3                  1020

2017-06-08  3                  1020

2017-06-09  3                  1050

2017-06-10  3                  1050

Comment: Does the Grouping_ID change from n to n+1 after 2017-06-10 every time?

Comment: So I want the max value till date for dates between 2017-06-01 and 2017-06-10 for each grouping id. So the grouping id is as per the groupings available

Comment: Would you have a template with 2 columns(date, grouping id) for yourself that has 10 dates x 3 grouping id entries(30)? I can build a logic with that template.

Comment: I can get days x grouping through a query easily.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you have the `TEMPLATE_TABLE` that has all days x all grouping IDs data, you can try below two queries:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 AS
SELECT A.DATE, A.GROUPING_ID, B.VALUE
FROM
TEMPLATE_TABLE A
LEFT JOIN
GIVEN_TABLE B 
ON A.DATE = B.DATE AND A.GROUPING_ID = B.GROUPING_ID
ORDER BY A.GROUPING_ID, A.DATE;
```

Above table `TABLE_1` will pad values for matches and NULL for non-matches.

You can use this table to find maximum values till a given date for all dates through a self join given in the below query:

```
SELECT B.DATE, B.GROUPING_ID, MAX(A.VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM
TABLE_1 A
INNER JOIN
TABLE_1 B
ON A.GROUPING_ID = B.GROUPING_ID AND A.DATE<=B.DATE
GROUP BY B.DATE, B.GROUPING_ID;
```

Hope this works. Let me know if this doesn't.

Comment: My template table has 4324 rows.
First join returns 4324 rows.

When I execute second query with inner join, I get 1707 rows. Does not seem to be working.

Comment: I made an edit by adding a group by clause that was missing earlier in the second query. I also tried with dummy tables and it worked fine. Could you try the edited query?

Comment: Lesser number of rows when I add this additional clause

Comment: Check [here](http://rextester.com/VJDAX5135). I have used int values instead of dates for illustration.

Comment: Yes, it works. I had a mistake in my query. Thanks a lot